# Time complexity of Search in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity

In my opinion, the best case time complexity of the following code is O(1), i.e. number to be searched is found as the first element but the worst-case time complexity is O(n**2) because there can be n number of elements in each array and there can be n arrays in 2d array (nested loop to search)

Please let me know if you agree/disagree.

Note: below code is an example of an NxN array. My question is in general for NxN array and not specific to the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

int M[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int x = 20;

bool searchM(){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      if(M[i][j]==x)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
} 

int main() {
  std::cout << searchM();
}
```

Comment: *below code is an example of an N-dimensional 2D array* -- What exactly does this mean?  A 2D array is short for "two-dimensional", so it is confusing calling something an N-dimensional 2-dimensional array.  If you mean that the number of rows and columns are the same, you should plainly state this, or maybe say an `NxN` array.  A two-dimensional array could consist of a million rows and 2 columns -- that's why you need to clarify your question.

Comment: it is not very meaningful to ask for complexity of finding an element in a `3x3` matrix. In the best case the first element you check is `x` in the worst case its the 9th. Asymptotic runtime considerations make sense only when the input size can (in principle) grow arbitrarily

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the question. Sorry for not being clear. I've changed it to NxN matrix (grow arbitrarily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function could search an arbitrarily-sized (instead of fixed-size) NxN matrix `M`, then what you're doing is a sequential search. For example:

```
int M[3][3] = { { 1,2,3 },{ 4,5,6 },{ 7,8,9 } };

bool searchM(int n, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (M[i][j] == x)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << searchM(3, 20) << std::endl;
}
```

Since the input size is N, it would be correct to say that the worst-case complexity of this algorithm is O(N<sup>2</sup>).